# How to fill entire rows with conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I have the below code: this only fills rows in column a, I would like all columns to be filled.

```
Sheets("Schedule").Cells.Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=m1=""Part"""
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
End With
```

I have made it select all cells to get around this but it hasn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula in

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=M1=""Part"""
```

is not correct. Just use

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$M1=""Part"""
```

instead and it will work.

**Note:**
The difference here is the `$` infront of the `M` which assures that the column is fixed but the row `1` is not and can iterate.

And I recommend not to use `.Select` and `Selection.` at all (this is bad practices and they should **always** be avoided).
Your code can be improved like this:

```
With Sheets("Schedule").Cells
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$M1=""Part"""
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all cells in sheet to turn blue when they have word "Part". then you should use this code.

```
Sheets("Schedule").Cells.Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=A1=""Part"""
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
End With
```

in case you want conditional to start at "M" column, you should use this line  `Sheets("Schedule").range("M:AAA").select` instead of `Sheets("Schedule").Cells.Select`.

Comment: Thanks, I basically want the following: if "part" appears in any cell in the m column, I would like to format the whole row to a colour.

Comment: Then simply replace `Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=m1=""Part"""` with `Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$m1=""Part"""`  (add $ sign in front of `M`)